# How to show previous period sales of items that didn't have sales in current month in Power Pivot?

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

When displaying prior month sales, I noticed that items with no sales in current month are missing in the Pivot Table output of the data model. However, the grand total sales includes sales of those missing items.

I created a small data model to replicate the issue: 2 tables (1 sales table and 1 calendar table) and it has 1 single DAX formula:

```
Previous Month Sales:=CALCULATE(sum([Sales]),PREVIOUSMONTH(Sales[Date]))
```

[image: table relationships]

In the output table, I would have expected 1 more item row for Potatoes, with 0 sales in current month and 31 in previous month.

[image: item row missing]

Is there a way to force-show Potatoes item in the pivot table above when selecting date 24/03/2019? Can this be achieved with DAX formulas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Date field from your Calendar (Date) table, for Time Intelligence to work as you intend:

So change your `Previous Month Sales` measure to:

```
Sales Previous Month:=CALCULATE ( 
        SUM ( Sales[Sales] ),
        PREVIOUSMONTH ( Calendar[Date] )
    )
```

I'd also recommend creating an Explicit Measure for Sales:

```
Sales Total:=SUM ( Sales[Sales] )
```

Now you can recreate your pivot output, using Date field(s) from Calendar in your slicer / filter, and you should get the output you require:

[image]

Comment: Very helpful answer. Your previous version before the edit also solved it. Just wanted to mention 2 additional maybe obvious things I had to do: (1) wrap the date variables to solve an error: StartDate = Date.From(List.Min(Sales[Date])) and (2) set the DateTable as the calendar table. thank you!

Comment: I somehow missed, the first time around, that you already had a Date Table and relationships set up!